# How to call IE CSS gradient property --> Filter from Jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, gradient

I have been trying to call filter css method from jquery for IE, but I am aint b able to do so?

What I using ?

```
    $('.gtob').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-image","-moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #373737, #000000)");
        $(this).css("background-image","-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#373737), to(#000000))");
        $(this).css("filter","progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#373737', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0)");
    });
```

The first two lines works great for Firefox, Safari and Chrome but the IE statement give no response :(

So, Anyone know how to do it ?

P:S! I have tried -ms-filter Nothing happens

Comment: Does the css work when you apply it via `.gtob:hover {filter: etc...}`

Comment: @Jossiah No, man it´s doesn´t with hover? but filter in css works without hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that your code would be much cleaner if you moved those styles to a class in your stylesheet, and then do `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` for your mouseover.

You didn't specify which version of IE you're working with, but for what it's worth, `filter` is for IE6 and IE7, but IE8 requires `-ms-filter`. The latter also requires you to escape the quote marks in the filter string.

Finally, you may want to check out [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com), which is a hack for all versions of IE to allow them to support CSS gradients and border-radius in a slightly more standards-compliant manner.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for css3pie, I give it a try. My target is IE6+

Comment: I agree that when possible, you should separate styles from your javascript, but sometimes MS Filters and using classes like that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think gradient has to be capitalized?

```
  $('.gtob').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-image","-moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #373737, #000000)");
        $(this).css("background-image","-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#373737), to(#000000))");
        $(this).css("filter","progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient( startColorstr='#373737', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0)");
    });
```