# jQuery fadeTo() Creates Black Box in IE 9 Using Shadow Filter

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to simulate a black outline to white text on a jquery image slider/Accordion based on [Accordion Image Menu](http://web-argument.com/2011/03/07/jquery-accordion-image-menu-plugin/)  .  This works great until IE 9 comes into the picture.  I'm using Jquery fadeTo() to handle opacity.  Originally I was using animate() but I have the same trouble with that.  Whenever the text fades in or out I'm getting a black box where the span elements are.  The black box seems to quickly appear then disappear with a flash type effect when fadeTo() starts and then again when fadeTo() finishes. This does not occur with IE 7 or 8.  Looks great there.

**In an IE-only stylesheet I have**

```
#acc-menu1 a span.left-arrow{
 position: absolute;
 left: -5px;
 bottom: 0;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 3em;
 margin-right: 25px;
}

#acc-menu1 a span{
 font-family: "Helvetica",sans-serif;
 bottom:0;
 left:20px;
 width:100%;
 display:block;
 padding:2px 5px 5px;
 position:absolute;
 font-size:1.8em;
 font-weight: bold;
 height:25px;
 line-height:18px;
 color: #FFF;
 /*filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(offX=1,offY=1,color=000000);*/
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=225,strength=2,color=black);
}
```

**HTML looks like this...**

```
 <div id="acc-menu1">
      <a href="#"><span>Link Name</span><img title="title" src="image source" alt="" width="w" height="h" /><span class="left-arrow">&laquo;</span></a>
      ... 3 more anchor tags ...
 </div>
```

*Link Name* is what fades in and out depending on which image is open.

**Here is the relevant js**

```
 var title = $('span',this);
 var arrow = $('.left-arrow',this);

 if (_this.menuSettings.fadeInTitle != null && title.length > 0) {
                    if (itemDim == _this.menuSettings.openDim) {
                        if (_this.menuSettings.fadeInTitle){
                            title.fadeTo('slow', 1);
                            arrow.fadeTo('fast', 0);

                        }else {
                            title.fadeTo('slow', 0);
                            arrow.fadeTo('fast', 1);

                        }
                    } else {
                        if (_this.menuSettings.fadeInTitle){
                            title.fadeTo('slow', 0);
                            arrow.fadeTo('fast', 1);

                        }else {
                            title.fadeTo('slow', 1);
                            arrow.fadeTo('fast', 0);

                        }
                    }
                }
```

I'm doing my best here to accommodate IE, but it's getting frustrating.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: IE9 supports the `opacity` CSS3 style, but the other two don't, and jQuery emulates it with a `filter` rule. Apparently two filters work together better than one filter and an opacity change. Would it be acceptable to disable the shadow effect during fading?

Comment: That would be completely acceptable.  I've tried adding `$('#acc-menu1 a span').css({"filter": 'none'});` at the beginning of the animate() function and re-applying the filter the end `$('#acc-menu1 a span').css({"filter": 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=225,strength=2,color=#000000'});` but that doesn't seem to make a difference.  Is that anywhere near what you were suggesting, Frederic?

Comment: Absolutely. Though `css()` does not seem to support adding `filter` rules reliably, maybe that's why it did not work. [A good workaround is to use a class instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413773/how-to-call-ie-css-gradient-property-filter-from-jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this looks like a conflict with your `filter` rule, I would suggest trying to neuter that rule during the fade animations. That might solve the problem, but I cannot test it so unfortunately I can offer no guarantee.

You can start by isolating the `filter` rule in its own class selector:

```
#acc-menu1 a span {
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    /* [...] */
    color: #FFF;
}

#acc-menu1 a span.shadow {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=225,strength=2,color=black);
}
```

Then, you remove the `shadow` class before fading and reinstate it afterwards. To avoid duplicating a lot of code, you can write your own `fadeTo()` method:

```
$.fn.shadowFadeTo = function(duration, opacity, easing, callback) {
    // 'easing' and 'callback' are optional, 'callback' takes precedence.
    if (typeof callback === "undefined") {
        callback = easing;
        easing = "swing";
    }

    return this.removeClass("shadow").fadeTo(duration, opacity, easing, function() {
        $(this).addClass("shadow");
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback.apply(this);
        }
    });
};
```

From there, you only have to write:

```
if (_this.menuSettings.fadeInTitle){
    title.shadowFadeTo("slow", 1);
    arrow.fadeTo("fast", 0);
} else {
    title.shadowFadeTo("slow", 0);
    arrow.fadeTo("fast", 1);
}
```

Comment: I seem to be having 2 issues now.  I'm getting an Undefined TypeError for callback for some reason. I tried using `==` instead but that did not help (grasping at straws here).  When I comment out `callback.apply(this)` things seem to be working better. Removing the class does help, but when it is added again, the black box flashes back.  Seems you've gotten me closer.  Thank you for your time.  Here is the url if it helps - http://wba.markchouinard.com

Comment: @Mark, the first bug was me being silly and failing to take *both* default arguments into account. I'll have a look at the other one when I get my hands on an IE9 next week. In the meantime, it would probably be easier if you could reproduce the problem in a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I had to dig out an old Windows machine to work on this myself.  I'll work on the fiddle today.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I notice now that if I change the opacity in the js to anything below 1 the black box/bar never disappears.  I don't know if that makes a difference or not, just thought I'd mention it.  Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzrJC/) I put together.  At least I learned that much today!